# How to Spy elements in an in-browser applet

Tags: selenium, selenium2, browser-automation, test-automation-framework

I am trying to automate user interaction on a web application which is having embedded java applet in it. Need a tool that can spy the objects in the java applet in browser .

The plan is to use FEST - swig library or anything similar to automate the user interaction on the objects in the applet.

Also this web application opens only on  IE browser.

Already I tried using IE webdeveloper, debug bar etc , but nothing is able to identify anything in the applet.
As I tried, QTP is able to identify the elements in the applet very easy, but I require something other than QTP as its not a feasibly solution in my environment.
Is there any open source tools that can support selenium to work with such in browser java applets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Java applet is written to be accessible then you can use UIAutomaion (replacement for MSAA since Windows Vista) to automate it.  Even if it is not 100% accessible, you may still be able to use UIAutomation.  QTP likely uses MSAA or UIAutomation under the hood to drive it's non-web automation.  There are a number of other solutions win32 automation that also use MSAA or UIAutomation that would probably work for you as well.